# "Black Bull" pubs in Northumberland

Tags: united-kingdom

What's the connection between the pub name "The Black Bull" and Northumberland? It seems like every other town here has one with the name!

Comment: Trivia is off topic.

Comment: If you want this question to stay open, I think it would be best to show some data supporting it, some reason why this connection might be important, etc. -- anything to show that this is a decent history question.

Comment: Next we will be fielding questions on why "The Pheasant Plucker* is such a common pub name n Canada.

Comment: It might have to do with [the Black Dinner][1] in 1440, the inspiration for *Game of Thrones'* own *Red Wedding*. 


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clan_Douglas#Black_Dinner

Comment: The Black Bull is a Yorkist device, the badge of Lionel Duke of Clarence third (2nd to survive infancy) son of Edward III and the ancestor through whom the house of York's claim to the throne derived. It was also a supporter (in the arems of) Edward IV and V and Richard III

Comment: It appeared with such frequency that it thought it likely that there was a local connection or story. In the area I went through there was a Black Bull in Matfen, Wark, Bellingham, Corbridge, Wylam, Blaydon, plus several in Newcastle.

Answer (score 1):

**The "Black Bull" is simply a common pub name nation-wide, and is not purely a Northumberland phenomenon**

The "Black Bull" appears in various lists of the most popular or common pub names [1](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/moslive/article-1374494/Red-Lion-White-Hart-Most-popular-pub-names-England.html), [2](http://www.pubsgalore.co.uk/search.php?search=black%20bull), and establishments bearing the name are to be found in areas as far flung as Buckinghamshire, Essex, Cambridgeshire, and Edinburgh [3](http://www.thedrinkingmansguidetoscotland.com/the-black-bull---leith-street---edinburgh.html).